# is there a better way to prove it?

Tags: convergence-divergence, numerical-optimization, rate-of-convergence

$\{x^k\}$ converge super linaerly to $x^*$ meant  $ \ \ \lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{||x^{k+1} - x^*||}{||x^k - x^*||^p}=r$  and  $\  \ 0<p<2$ and $\  \  $$r$ is constant.

is It true that The value of below limit is equal to one؟

if $\{x^k\}$ converge super linaerly to $x^*$ then  $$ \lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{||x^{k+1} - x^k||}{||x^k - x^*||}=1$$  ?

I wanted to prove it by definition, but I did not
Should I prove through the definition? Or is there a better way?

Comment: Your definition is incorrect.  Actually if $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} \frac{||x^{k+1}-x^*||}{||x^k-x^*||} = 1.5$ then $x^{k}$ does not even converge to $x^*$, it gets further and further away from $x^*$.

Answer (score 1):

If you split $x^{k+1}-x^{k}$ as $(x^{k+1}-x^{*})- (x^{k}-x^{*})$ you see that the limit is $|r-1|$, not 1. Perhaps you have stated the definition wrongly.

Comment: Rams Murthy Hello, thanks for your help, you are right,I modified the definition

Comment: Your definition still does not make sense. You have written $n\to \infty$ without saying what $n$ is. If the limit is taken as $k \to \infty$ then the value of the limit cannot be $k$. I think you should get the correct definition before any answer can be expected.

Comment: k is iteration, p is order of convergence, and r is rate of convergence

Comment: It does not get any results again, right?